# Add generic function implementation to protocol based on another generic function declaration

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'd like to create default implementation for convenience protocol function that just calls another protocol function, but can't figure out what's wrong with the code:

```
protocol RequestManagerProtocol {
    func perform<T: Decodable>(_ request: RequestProtocol) async throws -> (T, Int)
    func perform<T: Decodable>(_ request: RequestProtocol) async throws -> T // Convenience function
}

extension RequestManagerProtocol {
    func perform<T: Decodable>(_ request: RequestProtocol) async throws -> T {
        let (obj, _) = perform<T>(request) // Error: Cannot specialize a non-generic definition
        return obj
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would avoid adding convenience functions to the protocol definition, you can still have them in your extension, to keep the requirements of the protocol to a bare minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to `try await` the `perform` call.

And you have to annotate the (return) type rather than specifying the type in angle brackets

```
extension RequestManagerProtocol {
    func perform<T: Decodable>(_ request: RequestProtocol) async throws -> T {
        let (obj, _) : (T, Int) = try await perform(request)
        return obj
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you cannot specialize a function. So you cannot do this `perform<T>(request)`, you have to specify the type returned to your constant:

```
 let (obj, _): (T, Int) = try await perform(request)
```

Also, since you're not using the returned `Int`, you can simply do this:

```
func perform<T: Decodable>(_ request: RequestProtocol) async throws -> T {
    return try await perform(request).0
}
```